# How to add GraphQL Mutation with Django Nested Objects?

Tags: django-models, graphql, graphene-python

In my project I have an object called `Workflows` that has a 1:Many relationship with another object called `DataSources`.  I'm very close to being able to Create a New Workflow using a GraphQL Mutation.  Here's the pertinent code:

```html
class DataSourceInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    id = graphene.Int()
    database_name = graphene.String()
    table_name = graphene.String()

    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, id, context, info):
        node = get_datasource(id)
        return node


class CreateWorkflow(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        name = graphene.String()
        description = graphene.String()
        datasources = graphene.List(DataSourceInput)

    workflow = graphene.Field(Workflow)
    success = graphene.Boolean()
    errors = graphene.String()

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, input, context, info):
        name = input.get('name')
        description = input.get('description')
        datasources = input.get('datasources')

        try:
            workflow = WorkflowModel.create(name, description, datasources)
            return CreateWorkflow(workflow=workflow, success=True)

        except Exception as e:
            success = False
            return CreateWorkflow(workflow=None, success=False, errors=str(e))
```

What appears to be failing is the extraction of the DataSources that I wish to be associated with the new Workflow I'm creating.  I'm getting an error that says "unhashable type: 'dict'"

I don't know precisely what this error message is hinting I do.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Robert

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In python, if you specify it as a dictionary key, an error may occur.
For example.

```
>>> a = dict()
>>> type(a)
<class 'dict'>
>>> a[[0]] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

In the dictionary, a hash function is used to respond to the requirement of processing at low cost avoiding the whole search by **eq** when setting and acquiring the value.

An example of hashable is built-in int, str, tuple, frozenset.

The dict in this context is a Graphql request.
So first check if the value of key in query is hashable.
Also, it is desirable to put the query example I requested at the same time.

Comment: datasources = graphene.List(DataSourceInput)
This is unhashable